# Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Entity must has id

Tags: java, hibernate, spring-security

I don't understand what kind of mysticism. This method located in class UserService:

```
@Override
    public UserDetails loadUserByUsername(String email) throws UsernameNotFoundException {
        User user = repository.getByEmail(email.toLowerCase());
        if (user == null) {
            throw new UsernameNotFoundException("User " + email + " isn't found");
        }
       AuthorizedUser authorizedUser = new AuthorizedUser(user); // 1
       Objects.requireNonNull(authorizedUser);                   // 2
       System.out.println(new AuthorizedUser(user) + " 1");      // 3
       int userId = authorizedUser.getId();                      // 4
       return authorizedUser;                                    // 5
    }
```

In the lines which are numbered in comments,
why does everything go smoothly in line 1-3, line 3 goes to the console:

```
UserTo{id=100000, name='VadimUserAdmin', email='vadim@gmail.com'} 1
```

And in line 4, an exception is thrown:

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Entity must has id
    at org.springframework.util.Assert.notNull(Assert.java:201)
    at topjava.quest.HasId.id(HasId.java:14)
    at topjava.quest.AuthorizedUser.getId(AuthorizedUser.java:22)
    at topjava.quest.service.UserService.loadUserByUsername(UserService.java:64)
```

What should I do with this?

spring.security.version - 5.6.2

hibernate.version - 5.6.5.Final

class AuthorizedUser:

```
public class AuthorizedUser extends org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.User {

    @Serial
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    private UserTo userTo;

    public AuthorizedUser(User user) {
        super(user.getEmail(), user.getPassword(), true, true, true, true, user.getRoleSet());
        setUserTo(Util.userAsTo(user));
    }

    public int getId() {
        return userTo.id();
    }

    public void setUserTo(UserTo userTo) {
        userTo.setPassword(null);
        this.userTo = userTo;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return userTo.toString();
    }
}
```

class UserTo:

```
public class UserTo extends BaseTo implements Serializable {

    @Serial
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @NotBlank
    @Size(min = 2, max = 100)
    @ApiModelProperty(example = "New name")
    private final String name;

    @Email
    @NotBlank
    @Size(max = 100)
    @ApiModelProperty(example = "newmame@gmail.com")
    private final String email;

    @NotBlank
    @Size(min = 6, max = 32)
    @ApiModelProperty(example = "newmame123")
    private String password;

    @ConstructorProperties({"id", "name", "email", "password"})
    public UserTo(Integer id, String name, String email, String password) {
        super(id);
        this.name = name;
        this.email = email;
        this.password = password;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public String getEmail() {
        return email;
    }

    public String getPassword() {
        return password;
    }

    public void setPassword(String password) {
        this.password = password;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "UserTo{" +
                "id=" + id +
                ", name='" + name + '\'' +
                ", email='" + email + '\'' +
                '}';
    }
}
```

class BaseTo:

```
public class BaseTo implements HasId {

    @ApiModelProperty(hidden = true)
    protected Integer id;

    public BaseTo() {
    }

    public BaseTo(Integer id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    @Override
    public Integer getId() {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public void setId(Integer id) {
        this.id = id;
    }
}
```

class HasId:

```
public interface HasId {
    Integer getId();
    void setId(Integer id);

    default boolean isNew() {
        return getId() == null;
    }

    default int id() {
        Assert.notNull(getId(), "Entity must has id");
        return getId();
    }
}
```

What I do wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you call `HasId.id`, you call method `getId()` from `BaseTo.class`, which returns `null`. Change the method to

```
getId(){
  return this.id;
}
```

Comment: thank you very much, it really worked! Another counter question, then I don't understand how the interface determines from which class that implements it to call getId()?

I have 

---- public class BaseTo implements HasId ----

and 

---- public abstract class AbstractBaseEntity implements HasId ----